# Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, django-views

I'm creating a relation between two objects and the function to call for creating relation requires two ObjectId of the object between which the relation is to be created and the entire relation object.

The call to the object is made as follows:

```
create_realtion(a._id,relation_object,b._id)
```

The error is thrown as :  `Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array mongodb`

Comment: The data is not an array. That is what the error is telling you. You need to show how you have defined your classes. Also include the driver being used. MongoEngine perhaps?

Comment: yes, MongoEngine. So when the function call is made, it has to passed as a array ?

Comment: You need to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36495251/edit) your question to include the class details. Otherwise there isn't enough information here to answer.